# "ionic start project test" giving error ENOTFOUND github:443

Tags: node.js, cordova, github, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an ionic application but getting below error

Command:-
    ionic create testapp sidemenu

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443

"
Creating Ionic app in folder ~..\conference base
d on sidemenu project
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-base/archive/master.zip
Error Initializing app: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:26:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:77:26)

getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND github.com github.com:443 (CLI v1.7.8)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.6.4
OS: Windows 7 SP1
Node Version: v4.2.1
```

"

Please suggest how to resolve this, I am new in phonegap/ionic/nodejs

[EDIT] proxy has already been configured successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your ionic version. This command can't be launch with a CLI version under v1.7.10.

Have a look at the tutorial : https://creator.ionic.io/app/dashboard/help/videos

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting that same Issue.
I also set proxy, http-proxy for npm already but still getting issue
I Fixed this by setting proxy in ionic module as explained in this [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2014/04/02/Ionic-Framework-Getting-ionic-start-appName-Working-Behind-a-Proxy.aspx)

Basically you just need to add below line at line no 421 (approx. just before tunnel creation in code) in require.js for setting proxy and then this Ionic CLI will start working.

```
// hack to add proxy
    self.proxy = 'http://proxy-ip:proxy-port';
```